# Import Users From LDAP to Liferay

Tags: ldap, liferay

So, I'm using Liferay 6.1 CE, LDAP server with all my users and groups.
What I want to do is to import the users and their group from LDAP to Liferay.
I did the configurarion in the Cntrol Panel of Liferay with These Parameter :

### USER

Authentication Search Filter : (uid=@screen_name@)
Import Search Filter  :  (objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
Mapping (Screen Name --> uid , Password --> userPassword, Email address --> email, fullname --> cn, last name --> sn, uuid --> uid)
...
The "Test LDAP Users" gives me a result, so my config until now is correct !

Next for the Group :

### Group

Import Search Filter  :  (objectClass=posixGroup)
... for the mapping (Group Name --> cn , user --> memberUid)

Now, when I try to log in Liferay with my credentials from the LDAP it doesn't work...
Any idea to fix this issue ?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: I have this exception : Unable to import user ***** com.liferay.portal.UserScreenNameException.

Comment: If you have configured Liferay to login using screenNames, the screenName you import from LDAP should exist. Search `PortalLDAPUtil` for `UserScreenNameException` and you see why.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding

```
users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.LiberalScreenNameValidator
```

in you portal-ext.properties files. This allows liferay to handle underscores and numerals better in the username.